# Hashicorp Vault logs output lease resore complete and revoked lease id

Tags: kubernetes, devops, hashicorp-vault, vault

We have vault running 1.5.4 in k8s and the logs output as below:

2021-03-08T21:28:04.326Z [INFO] expiration: revoked lease: lease_id=auth/approle/login/sdvsvsvesx086bacsdcscse798ea050eba3xscscsczxacsc0af```

Please let me know do we have to do anything from our side to get rid of those messages. Thanks.

Comment: While you could turn off such logging (and loose a lot of other possibly useful output), is it really so bad to see secrets when they are revoked? After all that's when they loose their value anyway...

Comment: Hi thanks for replying @HiranChaudhuri, yeah it is giving more logs about that and looking at makes me feel like is there anything I am missing to do. btw how can I turn off those if there are not anymore value to look at them?